# How to read manufacturer information from SD card?

Tags: sd-card

I bought a few SD cards, from different sources.   They all are marked as SanSisk or Samsung with "speed class" of 10, and "UHS speed class" of 3.

I used Windows Powershell RoboCopy to copy several directories totaling ~40 GB to each card, and then compared the time taken to do so.  One of the cards took over 8 times as long (copying the same set of directories).

So, I'm wondering it the card was "relabeled" by the seller.

Is there any way, on Windows 10, that I could read any of the properties of the card ?   I've heard manufacturer info is saved somewhere on the card.

Comment: This question is more suitable for [su], as it is a general computing question. SO is strictly for questions related to programming. If you really have a *SanSisk* labeled card, it's a fake - the brand name is *SanDisk*.

Comment: Ohhhh thank you Ken  - I was about to buy hundreds of the SanSisk cards.